# Core Data: updating a managed object doesn't call the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an issue with my table view not updating when I programmatically change some existing managed object property. I would expect my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to be called in such case, but it isn't.

Apple doc says:

> An instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` uses methods in this protocol to notify its delegate that the controller’s fetch results have been changed due to an add, remove, move, or **update** operations.

In more details, my managed object as an int property called `status` that takes values from an `enum`. My table view only display those objects which have their `status` equal to `upToDate` (one of the enum's values). To do so, my FetchedResultController has a predicate that tests for that status:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doc.status == %d", upToDate];
```

It works fine, but updates are not reflected when I change an out-of-date object back to status `upToDate`. My code is modified from Apple's template.

Here is what I tried:

```
myObject.status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:upToDate];
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
[managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
[myTableView reloadData];
```

And finally, I managed to have my table view update with a call to:

```
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[myTableView reloadData];
```

But even then, none of my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods get called, in contradiction with Apple's doc. Additionally, no smooth animation happen.

I expected `controllerWillChangeContent:`, `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`, and `controllerDidChangeContent:` to be called.

I suppose I missed something, possibly something obvious, but I can't see what. Does `performFetch:` need to be called every time some managed object potentially changes? When does the `NSFetchedResultsControllerD` *really* call its delegate?

Thanks.

Comment: Any solutions you found for this behavior? Am facing similar situations where my delegate callbacks are never triggered for an update operation. Addition of new objects or deletion of existing objects anyhow does call the delegate method though. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If the FRC delegate methods are never being called regardless of the type of change, then the most likely explanation is that the delegate is not properly configured. It could be caused by:

1. The delegate is simple not set
2. The delegate class does not declare the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol.
3. You make the changes in another context without merging.

I would suggest capturing the error return of the save operation to make sure nothing is happening with the save.

The FRC should be notified of any changes to its context regardless of whether they have been saved or not. The FRC should then notify its delegate.

Comment: 1. `aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;` is present
2. Double checked.
3. I have only one context ever, which is passed along from the app delegate.
As I wrote, it's basically the vanilla Apple code. Any other idea what else to check?
And of course I capture the error from save. I just simplified my code snippet for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this just happen with a initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName: where then sectionNameKeyPath is non-nil.  If I make sure that sectionNameKeyPath is nil then I get the updates like I would expect.

I am still investigating why this is happening